# Javascript working on one host but not the other

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have recently uploaded a site I'm working on to a clients server. Unfortunately they are only running PHP 4.3, so a few things aren't working but some of my Javascript isn't working which is strange. Can anyone give me any insight into this? Here is the site that is functioning (PHP5+): http://involutionstudios.net/earthrover

And here is the site that isn't:

http://earthtest.monpjc.com/ (PHP 4.3)

As you will be able to see once you compare the two site the Javascript for the centre console isn't working correctly and the images are failing to display.

There is no errors using F12 on Chrome, from F12 I can also see that the images are loading, so it's not a problem with incorrect directory paths.

The Twitter feed not loading isn't the problem as that's to do with PHP.

Any help would be great :)

Thanks

Comment: What doesn't work? *`so a few things aren't working`* is not very descriptive.

Comment: Have you checked the 2 sites? The entire centre console functionality has stopped working on one site but fine on the other. They are coded exactly the same. So I'm just baffled as just changing the host shouldn't affect Javascript. It's not the PHP I'm worried about I can sort that.

Comment: a js file is commented out typingtext.js on one

Comment: Yes, sorry. Forgot to mention I commented that out because it was causing errors. (That's just for the twitter feed)

Comment: @Liam: You're missing the `<body>` tag on one.

Comment: @AmalMurali Unfortunately that was missing on the working site :) Thanks for spotting it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images are loaded on second, but they are not visible because you are missing twitter div there, putting even empty `<div id="twitter"></div>` before slider will shift slider div to correct place as it does on first site